# Matlab Script Called Before Each Run

Tags: matlab

I have some init commands in a m-file on disk. Depending on where the user is executing from, the contents of that init file will will change.

I'm wondering if there is a way to have Matlab automatically call this init script every time a script begins execution (either via the Run key or by requesting a call to a function in the interpreter).

I've looked at the startup.m script and that won't work as it is only executed when Matlab is first started but I want something that runs each time a script begins execution.

I've also thought about placing some boilerplate code at the top of the script file, but, that doesn't work in cell mode as the script may start execution part way through the script which would skip the boilerplate code.

Comment: "_that doesn't work in cell mode as the script may start execution part way through the script_". So basically you want to run a script which has to run *potentially before each instruction* (imagine the user run the script line by line) ... Not possible. Besides, a good 'initialization' only has to take place one time, why do you want to run it so often ?

Comment: This is a strange-sounding requirement.  Consider providing a use-case for assistance in finding a different way to accomplish it.

Comment: The use case is that we have an external tool that assembles a workspace. Matlab is then invoked and the Matlab path needs to be updated to be able to see the different M-files throughout the workspace. If this is done in startup.m, it only works when Matlab is started and if the user moves the directory around to a different working copy they get a stale Matlab path. Also, it is possible to re-run this external tool which might change the workspace in such a way that the Matlab path is invalid.

Comment: As a follow-on, I realize there is the option of simply restarting Matlab. However, there has been some blow-back about that approach. The designers prefer to always use the same instance of Matlab.

Comment: Hoki: Good point, I had not thought about stepping a script line by line and the effect of re-calling an init script each time. Point taken.